# Are solutions of the forced Navier–Stokes equation less regular than those of the Stokes equation?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, navier-stokes

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$ be a smooth, bounded domain and $T > 0$. Let us consider
\begin{align*}
 \begin{cases}
 u_t + \kappa (u \cdot \nabla) u = \Delta u + \nabla P + f(x, t), \quad \nabla \cdot u = 0, & \text{in $\Omega \times (0, T)$}, \\
 u = 0 & \text{on $\partial \Omega \times (0, T)$}, \\
 u(\cdot, 0) = u_0 & \text{in $\Omega$}
 \end{cases}
\end{align*}
either with $\kappa = 1$ (Navier–Stokes equation) or with $\kappa = 0$ (Stokes-equation or linearized Naiver–Stokes equation) and a given function $f$.

If $\kappa = 0$, then one obtains various a priori estimates by semigroup theory. For instance, for $p \in [1, \frac32)$ we have the estimate
\begin{equation}\tag{$\star$}\|u\|_{L^\infty((0, T); L^\frac{3p}{3-2p}(\Omega))} \lesssim \|u_0\|_{L^\frac{3p}{3-2p}(\Omega)} + \|f\|_{L^\infty((0, T); L^p(\Omega))},\end{equation}
where the implied constants may depend on $\Omega$, $T$ and $p$, but not on $u_0$ or $f$. Moreover, estimates in $L^p$-$L^q$ with $p < \infty$ follow from maximal Sobolev regularity etc.

**My question is, whether there is a a known setting where an estimate holds for the system with $\kappa = 0$ but fails to hold if $\kappa = 1$.** Surely this is a difficult question in general, for instance all solutions to the Stokes equation with $f \equiv 0$ are bounded for smooth initial data – and we are still quite far from proving or disproving something similar for the Navier–Stokes equation.

However, I wonder whether we can say something for rather weak regularity classes for $f$. If $$f \in \big(L^\infty((0, T); L^2(\Omega)) + L^2((0, T); W_0^{1, 2}(\Omega))\big)^\star,$$
then one can hope to obtain a priori information for $u$ in $L^\infty((0, T); L^2(\Omega)) + L^2((0, T); W_0^{1, 2}(\Omega))$ by the usual energy identity, which depend on the corresponding norm of $f$. On the other hand, if we consider function classes where this does not work (such as $L^\infty((0, T); L^p(\Omega))$ for $p < \frac65$, I guess), I do not see how to obtain any useful a priori estimates.

Thus, it is conceivable that one could indeed prove that an estimate of the form ($\star$) does not hold for the Navier–Stokes equation when $p$ is small. Is this known for any such class of functions?

To be clear, I am not asking whether any problems at the level of local existence arise, but rather whether there is a sequence of smooth $u_0$ and $f$, such that the corresponding classical solution $u$ to the Navier-Stokes equation exists at least until time $T$ and for which the right-hand side in ($\star$) is bounded but the left-hand side blows up. I would also be interested in settings with other boundary conditions, or the system on the whole space or other spatial dimensions etc.